# PVLib tmy and rain/cloud cover

Tags: pvlib

If modeling a new solar panel system with PVLib, is it necessary to factor in cloud cover and rain if I have tmy (typical meteorological year) data?

Comment: I assume that you're data include global horizontal irradiance (GHI), and/or diffuse and direct irradiance? If so, then the cloud cover is already accounted for, and you should just use these irradiance values as they are. I suppose the only reason you would use rain would be if you plan to model some kind of soiling?

Comment: Yes it does.  DNI, GHI, DNI are all in the tmy.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Adam's comment, cloud cover is included in the tmy data with the DNI, GHI and DNI parameters.